# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'splitlines' When Saving Output Input To File

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting a "AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'splitlines'" when I go to save the users input to a file.

```
def testfunction():
    global names, type, length

    while True:
        name = input("Name: ")
        type = input("Type: ")

        if type == "Length":
            length = input("Length: ")

            output_file = open("Test.txt", "w")
            output_file.write(f"""
            {length}
            """).splitlines()
            output_file.close()


        return name, type

testfunction()
```

Comment: put it in a with statement to use the context manager

Answer (score 1):

`output_file.write` returns the number of characters written in the file, so you're calling `.splitlines()` on a int. You should probably remove the `.splitlines()`.

Comment: Oh I read somewhere thats how you remove the indenting of the file once its saved so it doesnt look funny is it not?

Comment: Half truth. It splits a string by line separators, so if I have `"a b c d /n e f g h".splitlines()` the result will be `["a b c d ", " e f g h"]`. So when you read a file, you can use that method to split these lines into a list.

Comment: If you don't mind telling me how would I stop it from saving the input like in the "middle" of the file? Well also keeping its formatting? (More will be added later so asking now lol) Thanks!

Comment: You should "format" your string exactly how you want it to be written by adding `\n` as line separator inside of it. If you just want to write a new line everytime you write something, you should use `open(file, 'a')` when opening the file.